# Get day from Date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

I want to get day from date. Suppose my date is `03-08-2013` it is in `d-mm-yyyy` format so I just want to get `d`and that is 03 from above date so I try this code but it does not work

**Note**
I want to do it without including any js

```
var date = '08-03-2013';
var d = new Date(date);
alert(d.getDate());
// 2nd way
alert(date.getDate());
```

it alert `NaN`. What is missing in this code? 
here is jsfiddel Link [Jsfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/v4a73/)

**UPDATE**

Comment: your `data` var is of type `String` not `Date`, You cannot call `getDate()` method on type `String`

Comment: What is wrong with the first way (`alert(d.getDate())`)?

Comment: @putvande it's alert NaN with first way

Comment: @putvande `new Date('03-08-2013')` doesn't parse the date correctly so it won't return what's expected.

Comment: @putvande `d.getDate()` gives me `8` which is the month, not the day.

Comment: What date is it you are looking for? The 3rd of August or the 8th of March? Because you are getting the 8th of March with your code. Your format needs to be `mm-dd-yyyy`.

Comment: @putvande No. It should be an [RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse). `mm-dd-yyyy` won't work reliably cross-browser.

Comment: The 3rd of August I want to get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date parsing in JS (and many languages, for that matter) is problematic because when the input is a date string, it's fairly ambiguous what piece of data is what. For example, using your date (August 3, 2013) it could be represented as

- 03-08-2013 (dd-mm-yyyy)
- 08-03-2013 (mm-dd-yyyy)

However, given *just* the date string, there's no way to tell if the date is actually August 3, 2013 or March 8, 2013.

You should pass your date values independently to guarantee the date is correctly parsed:

```
var
    str = '08-03-2013',
    parts = str.split('-'),
    year = parseInt(parts[2], 10),
    month = parseInt(parts[1], 10) - 1, // NB: month is zero-based!
    day = parseInt(parts[0], 10),
    date = new Date(year, month, day);

alert(date.getDate()); // yields 3
```

- [MDN documentation for `Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Since when is month zero-based?

Answer (score 2):

Use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).  It's parsing ability is much more flexible than the `Date` class.

```
var m = moment('03-08-2013','DD-MM-YYYY');
var dayOfMonth = m.date();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't know the regional settings of your visitors.

If you know the format of the string is always `d-mm-yyyy` then just parse the value yourself:

```
function GetDay(rawValue) {
    var parts = rawValue.split("-");
    if (parts.length === 3) {
        var day = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
        if (!isNaN(day))
            return day;
    }
    alert("invalid date format");
    return null;
}
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/kSnvz/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Use this it that which you want..

```
var date = '08-03-2013';
date=date.replace(/([0-9]{2})\-([0-9]{2})\-([0-9]{4})/g, '$3-$2-$1');
var d = new Date(date);   
alert(d.getDate());
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't know who down-voted this but it works in my end..
alert shows 8

Comment: Yep, but OP is looking for 3, not 8.

Comment: but i shows the format in comment at right if s/he follow that then s/he will get right value..
that is //yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: @SarwarCSE this works but what if my format is dd-mm-yyyy?then this will not work btw vote up for this effort

Comment: @AzamAlvi You shouldn't "upvote for effort" if the answer is incorrect.

Comment: @Azam Alvi I have updated for format dd-mm-yyyy. please check that

Comment: SarwarCSE good job.Now it's work great.If @André Dion dont post his answer I must accept this answer.